# Hide the .jsp url extension in struts2 project

Tags: struts2

I am working in the struts2 web application.I want to do the mapping of my url such that the extensions like ".jsp" should be eliminated from the url.
So below is the snippet code of my web.xml.I want to do that my url show  /login instead of /login.jsp.

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>URLFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>example.MyFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>onError</param-name>
        <param-value>/login.jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>URLFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just access *all* your JSPs through Actions (and put them somewhere below `WEB-INF` to enforce this policy). It's easy to do with the "default action" of Struts2:

```
<action name="login">
    <result>/WEB-INF/pages/login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

I don't know how well this integrates with `ServletFilter`, maybe you'll have to turn the one mentioned in your web.xml into a Struts2 `Interceptor`.

Comment: Agreed; the nutshell version is that you should never access a page except through an action in a well-crafted S2 (or any framework) app.

Answer (score 1):

You can change url extension using property file as shown in below link :

http://www.aoiblog.com/change-url-extension-in-struts2/